# Intermittent 502 Gateway error, Nginx / Passenger / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, passenger, development-environment

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out these intermittent 502 errors that have seem to have been happening since day 1.

This usually seems to only happen in development environment, I assume that it's because I have quite a bit of assets that are being loaded.

This is the error in the browser, (Keep in mind it is always a different file that gets the 502 error, it can be either css, or js, sometimes no files get a 502 error)

```
GET https://example.com/assets/asset.self-368aecefa09656a2be5c72dc8e685b120363a3df812134cbd2dd998bafa179fd.js?body=1 502
```

In the nginx error log it shows this

```
[ 2016-11-21 13:17:43.2054 17184/7efd3bfff700 age/Cor/Con/InternalUtils.cpp:112 ]: [Client 2-66] Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response
[ 2016-11-21 13:17:43.2112 17184/7efd3bfff700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:819 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 17411, application /home/user/app/public (development)
```

In the rails development.log it shows

```
Started GET "/assets/asset.self-368aecefa09656a2be5c72dc8e685b120363a3df812134cbd2dd998bafa179fd.js?body=1" for 64.72.213.76 at 2016-11-21 13:24:24 -0700
Started GET "/assets/profile.self-c0665056b47c3ab674073339b59398e0dd63f2b5080c9418e2401dee223f31c6.css?body=1" for 64.72.213.76 at 2016-11-21 13:24:25 -0700
Started GET "/assets/ratings.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for 64.72.213.76 at 2016-11-21 13:24:25 -0700
```

Here is my nginx.conf

```
user  user user;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  2048;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;
    index   index.html index.htm;
    server {
        listen              443 ssl;
        server_name         example.com;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        root /home/user/app/public;

        location / {
          passenger_enabled on;
          passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
          passenger_buffers 16 32k;
          passenger_buffer_size 64k;
          passenger_intercept_errors on;
          passenger_app_env development;
          auth_basic "Restricted Content";
          auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        }
    }
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    fastcgi_buffers 16 32k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_buffers 8 16k;
    proxy_buffer_size 32k;
    server {
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }
        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
        }
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to disable some gems that were causing prolbems

commented these lines in my Gemfile:

```
#gem 'figaro'
#gem 'therubyracer'
#gem 'cocaine'
#gem 'pry'
#gem 'pry-doc'
#gem 'roadie'
#gem 'public_activity'
#gem 'stackprof'
#gem 'activerecord-reputation-system'
#gem 'rails-perftest'
#gem 'ruby-prof'
```

Comment: i do not think this resolves the error did you do anything else as well.

Comment: I think I ended up realizing these gems weren't causing the problem but it was a much bigger issue with nginx and/or my server , however I completely forgot what I did to fix it :/